# How to random many link in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = {
  msg: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  link: "http://www.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com"
};
r_text[1] = {
  msg: "bbbbbbbbbbbb",
  link: "http://www.bbbbbbbbbbbb.com"
};
r_text[2] = {
  msg: "ccccccccccccccccccccc",
  link: "http://www.ccccccccccccccccccccc.com"
};
r_text[3] = {
  msg: "gggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
  link: "http://www.gggggggggggggggggggggggggg.com"
};
r_text[4] = {
  msg: "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt",
  link: "http://www.ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.com"
};

var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());

document.write("<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><center><FONT SIZE=72><FONT COLOR='#FFFFFF'><a href='" + r_text[i].link + "'>"+
  r_text[i].msg + "</a></FONT></center><br />");
```

This is the result but what to do when I have a thousand links?

Comment: Don’t use document.write. And also, use CSS instead of the font tag.

Comment: if you have a thousand link - it's the same code!! because `Math.floor(1000 * Math.random())`   will give you a number from 0 to 999 - just like `Math.floor(5 * Math.random())` gives you 0 to 4 - obviously you'll want to create those links a different way - but you didn't ask about that - as to how you would do that ... there's about a 1000 different ways - where do the links come from

Comment: when in php code only function worklist() {
 if (file_exists('lost/pawa.txt')) {
  $myfile = fopen("lost/pawa.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
  while( $i < 5000) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is to build a string then write to the DOM (rather than write to the dom each iteration). You can randomize your array first, then `map` the random indexes to HTML and finally append the document with it.

```js
/* For testing - this will simulate 10000 links */
let r_text=[], p = "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat".split(" ");
for(let x=0;x<10000;x++) {
let n=6, m=[];
while(n-->0) m.push(p[Math.max(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * p.length-6))])
r_text.push({msg: m.join(" "), link:'https://google.com'})
}
 

// ye-olde Durstenfeld shuffle
const shuffle = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
// set up your indexes
let all = [], x
for (x = 0; x < r_text.length; x++) all.push(x);;
all = shuffle(all); // randomize

// map over the html
let html = all.map(i => `<div class='item'><a href='${r_text[i].link}'>${r_text[i].msg}</a></div>`).join('');

document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much Kinglish but when i have many link still input one by one? can i curl from another server example input from a.com/linklist.txt

Comment: Please give a clear example, I don't understand. So you curl, get one or more new URLs and then you want to add them to the list?

Comment: The code above only shows a few random links, but my question is can I randomize many links? if in php, as far as I know, with the curl code then the address of the intended link will display a very large number of links  this example when i use php code https://ibb.co/KK63qmY with curl

Comment: So let me get the sequence right: the html page sends an ajax request to a PHP page that runs a curl request and gets a huge number of link/msg pairs. Those all get returned through ajax to the webpage and you're asking how to incorporate those into this solution? Did I get that right?

Comment: ok, I've set it up to generate 10,000 links and messages. Please accept this as the answer Thx

Comment: Dude You Are SO COOLL man thx a lot but i want ask again this is random all from list let r_text=[] when i want to give word in front can? and the resulting link is google.com/?result-from-random thanks man

Comment: see this line? `all = shuffle(all)` this randomizes ALL the links you have. for your original code, you'd use it like `r_text = shuffle(r_text)` - note that you also need that whole `shuffle` function above it.

Comment: thanks Kinglish for your help i hope you get reply from GOD, God Bless you

Comment: Just you clicking the checkmark next to the answer is thanks enough, so if you would be so kind, do that and we'll call this thing answered  :)

Comment: omg i am sorry kinglish i am new on stackoverflow sorry ohh yes I want to ask it possible if 2 domains are displayed? example google.com and yahoo.com ?

Comment: can i add 2 domain?

Comment: i am try to give another domain not showing for the code
r_text.push({msg: m.join("-"), link:'https://google.com/'})
r_text.push({msg: m.join("-"), link2:'https://yahoo.com/'})
and then
let html = all.map(i =`<a href='${r_text[i].link}{{keyword2}}-${r_text[i].msg}.html'>{{keyword2}}-${r_text[i].msg}</a>, `).join('');
let html = all.map(i =`<a href='${r_text[i].link2}{{keyword2}}-${r_text[i].msg}.html'>{{keyword2}}-${r_text[i].msg}</a>, `).join('');
not showing error undeffined can you tell me why?

Comment: this my example code http://jsfiddle.net/34as2z8x/1/ can you tell me ? how to showing 2 domain google and yahoo?

Comment: I updated that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kinglish/L7a1rh8p/8/

Comment: this code only 1 word ? i am try to give code for(let x=0;x<10;x++) { but error thanks before have a nice day